# Float/Decimal Handling Problem In TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Why do I have different results? The second result is correct. But it is the correct way to handle this calculation?

```
const a:number= 81992.05;
const b:number= -60759.89;
const c:number= 21232.16;

const result = a + b - c;
//#result 3.637978807091713e-12
console.log("result "+result)

//#result 0
const result2 = a + (b - c);
console.log("result "+result2)
```

Comment: solution is to user ParseFloat(); const result = parseFloat((a + b - c).toFixed(2))